# Is $f(p)=\beta p^{\alpha}$ the unique nonnegative function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $\frac{f(p)}{f(1-p)}=\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{\alpha}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(p)\geq 0$ be a function on $[0,1]$. Suppose
$$
    \frac{f(p)}{f(1-p)}=\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{\alpha}
$$
for some constant $\alpha>0$ and all $p\in [0,1]$. A specific solution to this equation is
$$
    f(p)=\beta p^{\alpha}.
$$
The question is: is the power function given above unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is any (non vanishing) function satisfying $g(p) = g(1-p)$ for every $p\in [0,1]$, then also
$$
f(p) = g(p) p^\alpha
$$
is a solution.